# React: Provide tooltip for table column header

Tags: reactjs, html-table, hover, tooltip, columnheader

I'm pretty new to React.

How may add a tooltip to certain column headers in a table?

What I found/tried so far:

```
<th><HeaderSpecialColumn /></th>

const HeaderSpecialColumn = () => (
    <OverlayTrigger
      placement="right"
      delay={{ show: 250, hide: 400 }}
      overlay={<Tooltip {...props}>this will be the explanation for the column</Tooltip>}
    >
      <Button variant="info" size="sm">My special column</Button>
    </OverlayTrigger>
  );
```

This results in:

[image: first trial]

But the problem is that 'My special column' now looks completely different to the others because I introduced the Button. But I could not yet manage the hovering without it.

How can I get a tooltip for the `<th></th>` object with default header style?

P.S. Setting tooltip `placement="top"` always covers the header and does not place it above.

Comment: You could do many things, like why not just use span instead of button, or just remove the css from this particular button.

Comment: using span did it, thanks!